# How to compare two array of object and get common objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash, ramda.js

Hello guys I have two arrays

```
var elements = [{
        "id": "id_1",
        "type": "input",
        "businesstype": { "type": "text" }
    },
    {
        "type": "label",
        "id": "id_234"
    },
    {
        "id": "id_16677",
        "type": "div",
    },
    {
        "id": "id_155",
        "type": "input",
        "businesstype": { "type": "password" }
    }
]

var filterArray=[{type:'input',businesstype:{type:'text'}},{type:'div'}]
```

and want common obejct like

```
var output = [{
        "id": "id_1",
        "type": "input",
        "businesstype": { "type": "text" }
    },
    {
        "id": "id_16677",
        "type": "div",
    }
]
```

How do I compare these two objects to get equal objects from elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter it with a recursive approach for the nested objects.

```js
const isObject = o => o && typeof o === 'object',
      isEqual = (f, o) =>
          isObject(o) && Object.keys(f).every(k =>
              isObject(f[k]) && isEqual(f[k], o[k]) || o[k] === f[k]
          );

var elements = [{ id: "id_1", type: "input", businesstype: { type: "text" } }, { type: "label", id: "id_234" }, { id: "id_16677", type: "div" }, { id: "id_155", type: "input", businesstype: { type: "password" } }],
    filterArray = [{ type: 'input', businesstype: { type: 'text' } }, { type: 'div' }],
    result = elements.filter(o => filterArray.some(f => isEqual(f, o)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `filterArray` does not have further objects in its hierarchy, you can make do with this solution - see demo below:

```js
var elements=[{id:"id_1",type:"input",businesstype:{type:"text"}},{type:"label",id:"id_234"},{id:"id_16677",type:"div"},{id:"id_155",type:"input",businesstype:{type:"password"}}],filterArray=[{type:"input",businesstype:{type:"text"}},{type:"div"}];

var result = elements.filter(function(e) {
  return filterArray.some(function(f) {
    return Object.keys(f).every(function(k) {
      return e.hasOwnProperty(k) && Object.keys(f[k]).every(function(n) {
        return e[k][n] == f[k][n];
      });
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0;max-height: 100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Since you tagged Ramda)

Ramda already has many useful (object) comparison functions you can use to make the filter a bit easier to read. (i.e.: [`equals`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#equals) and other functions that use it under the hood, like [`contains`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#contains))

You could, for example, write:

```
const elements=[{id:"id_1",type:"input",businesstype:{type:"text"}},{type:"label",id:"id_234"},{id:"id_16677",type:"div"},{id:"id_155",type:"input",businesstype:{type:"password"}}];
const filterArray=[{type:'input',businesstype:{type:'text'}},{type:'div'}];

// Describes how to define "equality"
// i.e.: elements are equal if type and businesstype match
// e.g.: pick(["a", "b"], { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) -> { a: 1, b: 2}
const comparisonObjectFor = pick(["type", "businesstype"]);

// Compares an object's comparison representation to another object
const elEquals = compose(whereEq, comparisonObjectFor);

// Creates a filter method that searches an array
const inFilterArray = matchElements => el => any(elEquals(el), matchElements);

// Run the code on our data
filter(inFilterArray(filterArray), elements);
```

Running example [**here**](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20elements%3D%5B%7Bid%3A%22id_1%22%2Ctype%3A%22input%22%2Cbusinesstype%3A%7Btype%3A%22text%22%7D%7D%2C%7Btype%3A%22label%22%2Cid%3A%22id_234%22%7D%2C%7Bid%3A%22id_16677%22%2Ctype%3A%22div%22%7D%2C%7Bid%3A%22id_155%22%2Ctype%3A%22input%22%2Cbusinesstype%3A%7Btype%3A%22password%22%7D%7D%5D%3B%0Aconst%20filterArray%3D%5B%7Btype%3A%27input%27%2Cbusinesstype%3A%7Btype%3A%27text%27%7D%7D%2C%7Btype%3A%27div%27%7D%5D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Describes%20how%20to%20define%20%22equality%22%0A%2F%2F%20i.e.%3A%20elements%20are%20equal%20if%20type%20and%20businesstype%20match%0Aconst%20comparisonObjectFor%20%3D%20pick%28%5B%22type%22%2C%20%22businesstype%22%5D%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Compares%20an%20object%27s%20comparison%20representation%20to%20another%20object%0Aconst%20elEquals%20%3D%20compose%28whereEq%2C%20comparisonObjectFor%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Creates%20a%20filter%20method%20that%20searches%20an%20array%0Aconst%20inFilterArray%20%3D%20matchElements%20%3D%3E%20el%20%3D%3E%20any%28elEquals%28el%29%2C%20matchElements%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Run%20the%20code%20on%20our%20data%3A%0Afilter%28inFilterArray%28filterArray%29%2C%20elements%29%3B)

I don't think this is necessarily the best solution (in terms of reusability, readability), but I'd advice you to *not* inline deep object/array comparison methods since:

1. You're probably going to use them more than once
2. They are hard to understand/predict if not given the right name & documentation
3. They are prone to (small) bugs because of their complexity

In other words: since you've tagged lodash and Ramda, I can safely advice to *use a well tested, well used library for the comparison of your objects*.